# What does an empty intersection of two ruby arrays return?

Tags: ruby, hash, intersection, null

I'm trying to determine when 2 arrays have intersecting elements, if so do something.

What is returned when 2 arrays DO NOT have an intersection?

```
starthash.each { | key, val| 

        if (@final.keys & key != nil)

            puts "key"
            puts key                
            puts "final"
            puts @final.keys
            puts "here"
            puts val[0]
            toret.set_final(val[0],true)

        end

    }
```

key (is an array of numbers) is 0, and @final.keys (is an array of numbers) is 1, these differ so this block of code shouldn't be executed.

Is `nil` returned when 2 arrays have no intersection?

Comment: What is `@final`, and how does it relate to `starthash`? It would be a good idea for your question to set some values in your sample code, and to give your desired versus actual output. Otherwise it is hard to tell what you are asking. Also, it is not clear what `toret.set_final` is doing, and whether that is relevant to your question.

Comment: Hey Neil, I posted some clarifications, basically I want to know what is returned when 2 arrays DO NOT have an intersection? is it nil?

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand your question. Perhaps someone else will though

Comment: A quick test will show you that you get an empty array `[]` when 2 arrays don't have any elements in common. IRB/Pry are your friends ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The empty array is returned in the case of `a1 & a2` where `a1` and `a2` are arrays and they have no common elements.